# MySQL right query left join latest uploaded image from images table, with pagination

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select few data from first table and only last uploaded image from images table. My tables look like this:

table named data_property has fields (columns):

property_id, timestamp, label_town, label_sub, property_name, price_night, description (and others which I don't need in this case).

And table images with fields (columns):

image_id, property_id and ext. Images name is image_id and ext is extension of images.

Every property (property_id row) have 12 images in images table. I need to join only last uploaded image per property and show 10 property (`$recordsize = 10`) per page. I don't know how to organize my query

something like this:

```
SELECT 
    property_id, timestamp, label_town, label_sub, 
    property_name, price_night, description 
FROM 
    data_property 
    LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN (image_id, property_id, ext 
ORDER BY image_id DESC LIMIT 1) 
    FROM images ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT $recordstart, $recordsize
```

So, I need to select few field from data_property, join latest uploaded image which belong to that property, order by time of create property ad, sort from desc and show 10 property per page.

To get something like on this site: http://www.freehouseagent.com/property-for-sale/ireland/

Sorry for my bad English. I hope that you understand me.
Thanks and Best regards!

Comment: so you have 12 images for each property and you want to select the last uploaded one? how would you know when each image was uploaded while you dont have timestamp column in images table?

Comment: Last uploaded image have a largest id number (image_id it's auto-increment integer) image_id is also a name of image. User have possibility to delete images and upload another. I also have a timestamp column in images table so I can use also that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT 
    p.property_id, p.timestamp, p.label_town, p.label_sub,  p.property_name,
    p.price_night, p.description, i.image_id, i.property_id, i.ext 
FROM 
    data_property as p
LEFT JOIN images as i
ON p.property_id = i.property_id
GROUP BY p.property_id
ORDER BY p.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10
```

---

you can also try this for more accuracy:

```
SELECT 
    p.property_id, p.timestamp, p.label_town, p.label_sub,  p.property_name,
    p.price_night, p.description, i.image_id, i.property_id, i.ext 
FROM 
    data_property as p
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(image_id) as max, property_id
            FROM
                images
            GROUP BY
                property_id
           ) as n
ON p.property_id = n.property_id
LEFT JOIN
  images as i
ON i.image_id = n.max AND i.property_id = n.property_id
ORDER BY p.property_id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: try the other one as well it's better

Comment: If I have condition for something like select only properties 
WHERE p.label_town = London
where to put that line of code?

Comment: just before `ORDER BY p.property_id DESC`